# What does the sentence 该视频随即被上传至网络，转发量过万 translate to?

Tags: translation

I can't fully parse this sentence from [a news article](http://news.163.com/16/1117/08/C62E4ND5000187V9.html) (warning: article describes violence):

> 该[视频](http://www.dict.cn/%E8%A7%86%E9%A2%91)[随即](http://www.dict.cn/%E9%9A%8F%E5%8D%B3)被[上传](http://www.dict.cn/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BC%A0)至[网络](http://www.dict.cn/%E7%BD%91%E7%BB%9C)，[转发](http://www.dict.cn/%E8%BD%AC%E5%8F%91)量过万。
>   <sub>Gāi shìpín suíjí bèi shàngchuán zhì wǎngluò, zhuǎnfā liàngguò wàn.</sub>

This directly translates to something like:

> The above-mentioned video immediately [被 bèi (?)] upload to the Internet, and transmit to [more than 10,000 (?)]

I don't know why 被 is there; in the sentence it looks like it almost means "was".  And I'm not clear on what 量过万 means precisely (literally it's something like: "quantity exceed 10,000").

**Question**: What does this sentence translate to?

The video was mentioned earlier in the article [录像](http://www.dict.cn/%E5%BD%95%E5%83%8F)中[显示](http://www.dict.cn/%E6%98%BE%E7%A4%BA)。。。, so I believe that 该 here means "the above-mentioned" (it doesn't make sense to mean "should").

Comment: 转发 is something like repost/share/retweet, 转发量 = number of 转发, 过万 = exceed 10000. 该 means "this", 被 is there because the video didn't upload itself, it was uploaded.

Comment: The video was immediately uploaded to the web, and reposted over ten thousand times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the context of the article, I would translate this as:

> 该....视频.................随即.........被上传....至....网络，......转发量...过万
>   the video (was) immediately uploaded to the internet (and) the number of shares/retweets/reposts (is) over 10k

该 indeed means "the above-mentioned" but in most contexts you can just translate is as "the". In normal spoken conversation we'd say 这个/那个.

被 is a passive marker, indicating that the subject is the receiver of the verb rather than the do-er, i.e. the video did not "upload", rather it "was uploaded".

至 just means 到 (to). It's the formal character, common in news etc, but in normal conversation we would say 到.

The character 量 means "quantity" and can be added after a noun. For example "转发" is "forward/share/retweet" and "转发量" is "the number of forwards/shares/retweets".

过万 simply means "over 10000".